# Create a DataFrame for nutrients in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary, and I would like to create a DataFrame for 'nutrients' and also add a column for 'id
below is the PART of a list of dictionary.

Note: db is a list of dictionaries, for each dictionary I have 5 keys (description..nutrition), and each nutrition is a list of dictionaries, I want a data frame to include all dictionaries in nutrition and add a column for 'id'. id for the first dictionary is 1008.

```
db=[{u'description': u'Cheese, caraway',
  u'group': u'Dairy and Egg Products',
  u'id': 1008,
  u'manufacturer': u'',
  u'nutrients': [{u'description': u'Protein',
    u'group': u'Composition',
    u'units': u'g',
    u'value': 25.18},
   {u'description': u'Total lipid (fat)',
    u'group': u'Composition',
    u'units': u'g',
    u'value': 29.2},
   {u'description': u'Carbohydrate, by difference',
    u'group': u'Composition',
    u'units': u'g',
    u'value': 3.06}]]
```

Comment: Is that meant to be a list?

Comment: yes, db has 6000 dictionaries, I just copy paste part of it.

Comment: db is a list of dictionaries, for each dictionary I have 5 keys (description..nutrition), and each nutrition is a list of dictionaries, I want a data frame to include all dictionaries in nutrition and add a column for 'id'
for the first dictionary is is 1008

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(db[0]['nutrients'])
df['id'] = df.index
df
                   description        group units  value  id
0                      Protein  Composition     g  25.18   0
1            Total lipid (fat)  Composition     g  29.20   1
2  Carbohydrate, by difference  Composition     g   3.06   2
```

### Update

After understanding better what you intend I think this will do what you want. The idea is to create a list of dictionaries for all nutrients for all products and insert the id.

```
dict_merge = lambda a,b: a.update(b) or a
nuts = [dict_merge(nut, {'id': product['id']}) for product in db for nut in product['nutrients']]
df = pd.DataFrame(nuts)
df
                   description        group    id units  value
0                      Protein  Composition  1008     g  25.18
1            Total lipid (fat)  Composition  1008     g  29.20
2  Carbohydrate, by difference  Composition  1008     g   3.06
```

Comment: db is a list of dictionaries, for each dictionary I have 5 keys (description..nutrition), and each nutrition is a list of dictionaries, I want a data frame to include all dictionaries in nutrition and add a column for 'id'

Comment: I come up with this code, but doesnt work. I want to append all dictionaries in nutrition in the list_dataFrame.
list_dataFrame=[]
for dic in db:
    for k, v in dic.iteritems():
        if dic[k] =='nutrients':
            for dic in dic[k]:
                list_dataFrame.append(pd.DataFrame(dic[k]))

Comment: id for the first dictionary is 1008